Pulseeffects on Xubuntu 24.04.1
I've read that Xubuntu 24.04 ships with Pipewire instead of Pulseaudio. I've also read that in order for Pulseeffects to work with Pipewire, it needs to be version 5+. The version that ships with Xubuntu 24.04 though, according to https://packages.ubuntu.com, is 4.8.7, which means that it still needs Pulseaudio.
And the question is:
Does Pulseeffects work with Pipewire on Xubuntu 24.04 or not? And if not, what can we do about it?
Thank you.

Use easyeffects with pipewire. See also this question.
